# Animate a div?Proper selector?

Tags: html, css, animation, focus, transform

I have **Div A** and the **input** form. How do I achieve that the Div A does some transform animations when the input is focused? Is it possible to do it CSS only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the div right after the input, you can combine the `:focus` pseudo selector with the adjacent sibling selector `+`. Like this:

```
input:focus + div {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

For a demo, check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsr5n/)**

**EDIT:**

To smoothly rotate the div back to its original position when the input is no longer in focus, you might want to set it up this way:

```
div {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0);
    -o-transform:rotate(0);
    transform:rotate(0);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

input:focus + div {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsr5n/1/)**.

**Edit2**

If the div is placed before the input, or if there are many elements in between, you may do this using javascript. First rename the CSS selector `input:focus + div` into `.my_div.animate`. Then add/remove the `.animate` class with javascript like this:

```
// These have to match your elements
var my_input = document.querySelector(".my_input");
var my_div = document.querySelector(".my_div");

// Add class "animate" on focus
my_input.onfocus = function(){
    my_div.className = my_div.className + " animate";
};

// Remove class "animate" on blur
my_input.onblur = function(){
    my_div.className = my_div.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)animate(?!\S)/ , '' );
};
```

**Demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsr5n/2/)**.

Comment: E.g I got a div at the beginning of my html code and the input at the end and some stuff between it. Would it Still be possible to select it with the adjacent sibling selector "+"?

Comment: No, the `+` will only match the next sibling. If the div is placed before the input, or there are lots of content in between, you'll have to look for a javascript solution.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much. I had never expected such a fast answer, now I know why everyone loves this site

Comment: Just glad to help! Updated my answer with a javascript solution. Hope this suits your needs!

Comment: Yea it's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much!